# how to write a service class for doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Now, I am writing a php project with doctrine. But at service class, I need inject a EntityManager. How to do it? I have searched some answer, but They use a framework.

If donot use any php framework, How to write a service class and inject EntityManager?

Thanks a lots.

Comment: @Matt Whipple Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: My comment was due to not realizing the approach had changed with Doctrine 2 (compared to 1).  I don't have any concerete advice for this problem. "Without a framework" is a wide open space so it depends on how you want to handle it.  You could just the Doctrine static factory methods.  If you want to inject then you need some form of DI container.  My suggestion for the service classes would be to use constructor injection.  Depending on the infrastructure it may be simpler to use a service locator style object and pass that as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a class that obtains an EntityManager object, as per:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager

```
class EntityManagerService
{
    public static function getEntityManager() {
        // return EntityManager object as per documentation.
    }
}

$em = EntityManagerService::getEntityManager();
```

I hope this helps!